# Has a field goal or extra point attempt ever hit both uprights and the crossbar?

Tags: american-football, field-goal

During the 6 January 2019 NFL wild card playoff game between the Eagles and Bears, Bears kicker Cody Parkey [missed a game-winning FG](https://youtu.be/eKWQRC5t0K0?t=822) that hit the left upright and then the crossbar.

I found a video showing Jason Hansen of the Lions [hitting the right upright and then the left upright](https://youtu.be/NHtx0lhySfE?t=5) on a successful FG attempt in 2000.

I also found a video showing Gavin Patterson of South Alabama [hitting the left upright and then the crossbar twice](https://www.12up.com/posts/5729626-video-this-field-goal-hit-the-goalpost-3-times-and-somehow-went-in) on a successful FG attempt.

But has a college or NFL kicker ever hit both uprights and the crossbar on a FG or extra point attempt?

Comment: A guy in the Australian National Rugby League managed to do it: https://loiter.co/v/gif-chad-townsends-kick-denied-by-both-uprights-an/

Comment: Not that I heard of, but in practice it has happened:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNXPnzLe_rA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened on October 24, 2020 in the college football game Middle Tennessee-Rice. See [this article](https://247sports.com/Article/Quadruple-doink-missed-field-goal-costs-Rice-football-the-game-Middle-Tennessee-Blue-Raiders-153558030/Amp/?__twitter_impression=true).

[Here](https://twitter.com/MatthewBrune_/status/1320142256871976960) is the tweet with a video of the event.

Comment: Link to youtube video showing the quadruple doink: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBOT-oWKJWU